# Should I ignore *.layout and *.dependent from a .gitignore rule?

Tags: git, codeblocks

I am working on a C++ project with `Code::Blocks`. I notice that there are some `*.layout` files and `*.dependent` files.

Should I add them to `.gitignore`?

Edit:

I am also most sure that I can/should ignore `*.layout` files. But how about `*.dependent`?

Comment: Files generated by your build-system should almost always be in `.gitignore`. To know if those files are generated by your build-system and what they are used for, consult your build-system's manual.

Comment: @pmr this is the core of his question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, files that are *generated*, either for your convenience or during the course of the build process, should *always* be excluded with an ignore rule.  The actual question is where to put these ignore rules, and *Git* gives you two options here:

You should not add rules that are specific to your work environment to `.gitignore`.  A better place for such ignore rules is `.git/info/exclude`, which is local to your repository clone, but otherwise works just like `.gitignore` does.

In your case, the files in question are for an IDE that maybe nobody else on the team uses.  An ignore rule such as `*.layout` might not even make sense to other developers and confuse them.  So it is better to keep these exclusions private to your repository clone.

However, files that appear in the working copy independent of individual developer tools should be excluded via `.gitignore`; an example for that would be typical compiler artefacts such as `.o` files.

Keep `.gitignore` clean for others and don't put your own specific rules in there.  Obviously, if everybody on your team was using *Code::Blocks*, then it would be OK to exclude `*.layout` files in `.gitignore` (everybody needed that rule anyway, and it is unlikely that the rule would confuse people).

Finally, it might make sense to keep certain meta-information for IDEs under version control; an example for this are the `.project` files that *Eclipse* uses – **if** these are portable between developer machines, and only if everybody is expected to save and restore from the same `.project` file.  This really would be a matter of discussion in your team.

This is more a piece of "style advice" than a hard-and-fast rule.

Answer (score 0):

It just depends on whether you want to commit those files or not. If you didn't `git add` them, and don't plan to, you should add them to your `.gitignore`, since it will be more convenient for you.

To know if you should commit those files, you should know how your dev environment works. As it's been stated, most file generated by your IDE shouldn't be commited. But it's not always the case. For example when you create a new project in Eclipse, it generates a `.classpath`, and it's rather convenient to add this file to git.

If you're unsure if you actually need a particular file you could:

- Commit your project without this file
- Clone your repo locally (`git clone myProject myTemporaryClone`)
- Try to work with this clone

If you didn't, for example, commit the `.classpath`, eclipse will complain it can't find a solution in your clone. Hence you'll understand you're missing something. On the other hand, if you can work as-is with this clone, you likely committed everything you need. Hence you can `.gitignore` each other file of your initial repo.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the .layout only contains the names of the source tabs that you have opened in the editor and the positions.

I make an experiment. Deleted and then reopened the IDE and it started with no open files but without problems, so I think it is safe to ignore it.

Also because is just information of your particular state of work and not source related that you *should* ignore it.